# asp.net mvc render a webform as a partial in a razor view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I'm trying to use the asp.net webforms sitemap and menu control to build my asp.net mvc's sites navigation.

There are many tutorials about embedding razor views into webforms, but I want to go the otherway around. Embed a webform into a razor view.

Doing something like this looks eemi promising:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/test/menu.aspx")
```

Which presents an error:

```
Parser Error Message: 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage'.
```

Is there a value for Inherits that would allow this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh Duh, read the error message...

I changed the first line of the webform from this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="menu.aspx.cs" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
```

to this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="menu.aspx.cs" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

Then I ran into another issue about `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` being defined twice, so I deleted the *.designer.cs file and now its working.